# How to bypass AfterReceiveRequest() method while adding service reference

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have implemented a security mechnism which checks for certain token structure in the header block of a WCF service.

I have used an implementation of `IDispatchMessageInspector` interface and used `AfterReceiveRequest()` method for verification purposes.

Now when I want to add Service reference or try to update Service reference, or even try to see the **`wsdl`**, the validation runs and throws an Exception, because there is no header I seek for, because I am not acessing the service from a proper call where I add the token to the header.

So, I need to bypass security mechanism **only** when I want to get metadata, but keep it for service calls.

How and where can I provide this bypass functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the MessageInspector to the endpoint where you want to inspect the messages. Not to the endpoint supplying the meta data (WSDL).

[From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iendpointbehavior.applydispatchbehavior.aspx)